# Is it possible for a 4x4 matrix to curve a plane in 3D space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

I'm wondering if there is a 4x4 matrix that would curve a flat plane in 3D space.
One utility would be converting a plane into the surface of a cylinder in a way that is invertible.

I'm assuming that this is a form of non-linear algebra, since it doesn't maintain collinearity of points.

Comment: A matrix represents a linear transformation, so it's not possible.

Comment: The very definition of a matrix prohibits that

Comment: Thanks you two, if either would like to post that as an answer I will accept it.